# Load XML in Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, xml, isolatedstorage, windows-phone

I'm using the following code to create and load the xml in the isolated storage. At the first part it creates the file in the isolated storage if it doesn't exist, else it loads the already created/loaded in the isolated storage file.
The problem is when it tries to load the file it has (successfully) created/loaded in the first time the function was called. Here is the code

```
public void InitAch()
{
    using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (!storage.FileExists("Achievements.xml"))
        {
            using (Stream stream = storage.OpenFile("Achievements.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("Achievements.xml");
                xml.Save(stream,SaveOptions.None);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (Stream stream = storage.OpenFile("Achievements.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {

                XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(stream,LoadOptions.None);
                Lexis.Page4.Achievements.sheep = Int32.Parse(xml.Root.Element("BlackSheep").Value);
                Lexis.Page4.Achievements.singularity = Int32.Parse(xml.Root.Element("Singularity").Value);
                Lexis.Page4.Achievements.luke = Int32.Parse(xml.Root.Element("LuckyLuke").Value);
                Lexis.Page4.Achievements.gardener = Int32.Parse(xml.Root.Element("Gardener").Value);
                Lexis.Page4.Achievements.dumbo = Int32.Parse(xml.Root.Element("Dumbo").Value);
                Lexis.Page4.Achievements.joker = Int32.Parse(xml.Root.Element("Joker").Value);
                Lexis.Page4.Achievements.maid = Int32.Parse(xml.Root.Element("Maid").Value);
                Lexis.Page4.Achievements.mr = Int32.Parse(xml.Root.Element("MrWords").Value);
                Lexis.Page4.Achievements.secret = Int32.Parse(xml.Root.Element("Detective").Value);

            }
        }
    }
```

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: What happens exactly? Is there some exception? My first bet would be that `XDocument.Load` doesn't know path to your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!storage.FileExists("Achievements.xml"))
    using (Stream stream = storage.OpenFile("Achievements.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("Achievements.xml");
        xml.Save(stream,SaveOptions.None);
    }
```

In this code:

- Line 1: file doesn't exist
- Line 2: Create a new (empty) file
- Line 4: Load the (empty) file - **The file is empty at this point, nothing is loaded!** I'm guessing it throws either because of it, or because it can't resolve the name to the local storage - in any case this line is incorrect.
- Line 5: Saves the (empty?) XML document to the file

You'll need to fix the creation of the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you create an empty file and save it?  That seems a bit .. wrong.

Regarding the loading of an empty file, of course that's going to fail with an exception as soon as you access `xml.Root.Element("BlackSheep").Value`.

That element won't exist in an empty file, so `Element("BlackSheep")` is going to return null.  While the `.Value` property access will cause an exception.

So I'm not exactly sure what kind of help you need other than:

1. don't create an empty XML as there is no point; and/or,
2. add some code in your read to test whether there is actually anything in the file.